# using Node.js to make request, Yelp API error

Tags: node.js, api, server, request, yelp

I am writing my Node.js file now, which is to send requests to Yelp API and get the JSON response for client. I test my code in localhost.

I have seen the requesting url and both format and data are correct.

However, I get an error message when requesting this API:

> connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443

Here is my Node.js code:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  // data from the client
  var some_data;

  // send a GET request to Yelp’s API
  var https = require('https');
  var yelpMatch_url = encodeURI("https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/matches/best?some_data;

  var headers = {
     'Authorization': 'Bearer myAPI_KEY'
  };

  https.get({url: yelpMatch_url, headers: headers}, function(response) {
      var body = '';
      response.on('data', function (chunk) {
          body += chunk;
      });

      response.on('end', function () {
          // write response json
          res.write(body);
          res.end();
      });
  }).on('error', function(e) {
      console.log(e.message);
  });

}).listen(myPort);
```

Why this error ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks you are doing the request to https on your localhost.

Make sure your server is running locally, and update the get method as follows:

```
https.get(yelpMatch_url, {headers: headers}, function(req, response) {
    var body = '';
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function () {
        // write response json
        res.write(body);
        res.end();
    });
}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e.message);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! You guide me to think about the format. I figured it out that it should be like:

Comment: var https = require('https');
    var myurl = "http://www.example.com";
    var options = {
        url: myurl,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer myKeyID'
        }
    };


    https.get(options, function(response) {
        ... }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I figured it out. The format should be like this:

```
var https = require('https');
var myurl = "http://www.example.com";
var options = {
    url: myurl,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer myKeyID'
    }
};


https.get(options, function(response) {
    ... }
```